# How to Cover for Loop in test Class in vf

Tags: unit-test

I have created a test class with 44% coverage but my code is not covering the for loop part can you Please help me

**My Controller**

```
public class AttendanceCls{

    //public List<Session__c> UserTemp{get;set;}
    public List<ContactWrapper> listContactWrapper {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> selectedContacts{get;set;}
    List<Attendance__c> Atten = new List<Attendance__c>();
    public List<Session__c> UserTemp = new List<Session__c>();
    Public List<session__c> FetchID = new List <session__c>();
     Public List<Contact> ContID = new List <Contact>();
    Public static String Loc;
    Public Static String Cou;
    Public Id selectedSesId{get;set;}

    public AttendanceCls ()
    {
        listContactWrapper = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        searchRecord();

    }    
    public List<SelectOption> UserList
    {
        get
        {  

            UserTemp = [Select Name, Id, Date__c,Location__c,Course__c From Session__c ];

            UserList = new List<SelectOption>();

            //  system.debug('id testing            '+selectedSesId);

            for(Session__c temp : UserTemp)
            {
                UserList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Name));
                //      system.debug('Tempid        '+temp.id);

            }

            return UserList;
        }
        set;
    }
    public void searchRecord()
    {

        FetchID = [Select Name, Id, Date__c,Location__c,Course__c From Session__c where id = :selectedSesId ];
        for(Session__c ses : FetchID){
            Loc = ses.Location__c;
            Cou = ses.Course__c;
        }

        listContactWrapper.clear();
        for(Contact a:[select Id, Name,Location__c,Course__c from Contact where RecordTypeId in (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Student') And Status__c = 'Pursuing' And Location__c =: Loc And Course__c =:Cou limit 1000]) 
        {
            listContactWrapper.add(new ContactWrapper(a));
        }


    }

    public void processSelected() 
    {
        selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
        selectedContacts.clear();
        for(ContactWrapper wrapContactObj : listContactWrapper) 
        {
            if(wrapContactObj.selected == true) 
            {
                selectedContacts.add(wrapContactObj.acc);                
            }
        } 
        for(Contact c:selectedContacts){
            Attendance__c att = New Attendance__c();
            att.Name__c = c.Name ;
            att.Course__c = c.Course__c;
            att.Location__c = c.Location__c;
            att.Attedance__c ='Present';
            att.session__c = selectedSesId ;
            //system.debug('Name        '+c.Name);
            Atten.add(att);
        }
        insert Atten;
        searchRecord();
                }    
    public void DeActivateData() 
    {     
        selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
        selectedContacts.clear();
        for(ContactWrapper wrapContactObj : listContactWrapper) 
        {
            if(wrapContactObj.selected == true) 
            {
                selectedContacts.add(wrapContactObj.acc);

            }
            system.debug('selectedContacts      '+selectedContacts); 
        }      
        for(Contact c:selectedContacts){
            system.debug('selectedContacts Absent       '+selectedContacts);
            Attendance__c att = New Attendance__c();
            att.Name__c = c.Name ;
            att.Course__c = c.Course__c;
            att.Location__c = c.Location__c;
            att.Attedance__c ='Absent';
            att.session__c = selectedSesId ;

            Atten.add(att);

        } insert Atten;
        searchRecord();
    }




    // This is our wrapper/container class. 
    public class ContactWrapper 
    {
        public Contact acc {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public ContactWrapper(Contact a) 
        {
            acc = a; 
            selected = false;
        }
    }

}
```

**My Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class AttendanceTest {

    static testMethod void testMethod1() 
    {        
        Location__c Location = new Location__c();
        Location.Name ='Test Record';
        Location.Address__c = 'Test Address';
        Location.City__c = 'Test City';
        insert Location;

        Course__c Course = new Course__c();
        Course.Name = 'Test Course';
        Course.Duration__c = 2 ;
        insert Course;

        Session__c Session = new Session__c();
        Session.Course__c = Course.Id;
        session.Location__c = Location.Id;
        insert Session;



        Test.StartTest(); 

        PageReference pageRef = Page.Attendance; // Add your VF page Name here

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        AttendanceCls testAccPlan = new AttendanceCls();

        testAccPlan.processSelected(); 
        testAccPlan.searchRecord();
        testAccPlan.DeActivateData();
       // testAccPlan.ContactWrapper;
       // testAccPlan.AttendanceCls();
       // testAccPlan.FetchID;


        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```

**This is the Part where I cannot get code coverage**

1.

```
 for(Session__c ses : FetchID){
            Loc = ses.Location__c;
            Cou = ses.Course__c;
        }
```

2.

```
 for(Contact a:[select Id, Name,Location__c,Course__c from Contact where RecordTypeId in (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Student') And Status__c = 'Pursuing' And Location__c =: Loc And Course__c =:Cou limit 1000]) 
        {
            listContactWrapper.add(new ContactWrapper(a));
        }
```

3.

```
  for(ContactWrapper wrapContactObj : listContactWrapper) 
        {
            if(wrapContactObj.selected == true) 
            {
                selectedContacts.add(wrapContactObj.acc);                
            }
        }
```

4.

```
for(Contact c:selectedContacts){
            Attendance__c att = New Attendance__c();
            att.Name__c = c.Name ;
            att.Course__c = c.Course__c;
            att.Location__c = c.Location__c;
            att.Attedance__c ='Present';
            att.session__c = selectedSesId ;
            //system.debug('Name        '+c.Name);
            Atten.add(att);
        }
```

5.

```
 for(ContactWrapper wrapContactObj : listContactWrapper) 
        {
            if(wrapContactObj.selected == true) 
            {
                selectedContacts.add(wrapContactObj.acc);

            }
```

6.

```
  for(Contact c:selectedContacts){
            system.debug('selectedContacts Absent       '+selectedContacts);
            Attendance__c att = New Attendance__c();
            att.Name__c = c.Name ;
            att.Course__c = c.Course__c;
            att.Location__c = c.Location__c;
            att.Attedance__c ='Absent';
            att.session__c = selectedSesId ;

            Atten.add(att);
```

7.

```
 public class ContactWrapper 
    {
        public Contact acc {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public ContactWrapper(Contact a) 
        {
            acc = a; 
            selected = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set selectedSesId on controller to value of inserted record Id?

Answer (score 0):

To cover the first block, add line

```
testAccPlan.selectedSesId = Session.Id
```

after

```
AttendanceCls testAccPlan = new AttendanceCls();
```

To cover the second and the seventh block, insert a Contact record

```
Contact c = new Contact(
RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Student'].Id,
Status__c = 'Pursuing',
Location__c = Location.Id,
Course__c = Course.Id
)
```

after session insertion 
and also add lines

```
testAccPlan.Loc = Location.Id 
testAccPlan.Cou = Session.Id
```

To cover the third and the fourth and the fifth and the sixth block, switch lines

```
    testAccPlan.processSelected(); 
    testAccPlan.searchRecord();
```

and set `selected` attribute to true

```
    testAccPlan.searchRecord();
    testAccPlan.listContactWrapper[0].selected = true
    testAccPlan.processSelected();
```

Comment: Hai Patlatus, Thanks for Replaying to my post i have cleared the first section with your help but i cannot still reach the rest of the code